# How to install a PostgreSQL client

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL server setup on Box A. I want to connect to the server from Box B using psql. What do I need to install on Box B? I can't find a client installation binary for PostgreSQL. Or do I have to install the entire PostgreSQL distribution?

Comment: What is the OS? Most Linux systems will offer client-only packages.

Comment: What is your OS: Linux, Windows, others?

Comment: It's Ubuntu. I will look for a package then.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

On Debian the package you are looking for is called `postgresql-client` and I guess it will be the same on Ubuntu.

Comment: Where do I put pg_hba.conf though? It's supposed to be under the data directory, but there is none in a client only setup.

Comment: You need pg_hba.conf only on the server side, not the client side. It defines which client might connect from where and how.